# android: background phone state monitoring

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, telephony

I'm trying to create a background process which monitors the phone state and displays a toast message if the state is changed. so far, ive implemented these, but when i install and run. It does nothing. It wont display anything. Im posting my codes here. pls help me out.

StateMonitor.java

`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PhoneStateMonitor extends PhoneStateListener {
    Context context;

    public PhoneStateMonitor(Context context) {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context=context;
    }

    //This Method Automatically called when changes is detected in Phone State
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Phone State - "+state+" Incoming Number - "+incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//Giving the Message that Phone State Changed
        //Checking The phone state  
        switch(state)
        {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:    //Phone is in Idle State
            Toast.makeText(context, "Phone State is IDLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:  //Phone is Ringing
            Toast.makeText(context, "Phone State is RINGING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:  //Call is Received
            Toast.makeText(context, "Call State is OFFHOOK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
`
```

PhoneReceiver.java

```
`import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
//Automatically called when State Change is Detected because this Receiver is Registered for PHONE_STATE intent filter in AndroidManifest.xml
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    TelephonyManager manager;       
    PhoneStateMonitor phoneStateListener;
    static boolean isAlreadyListening=false;

    //This Method automatically Executed when Phone State Change is Detected
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        phoneStateListener =new PhoneStateMonitor(context);//Creating the Object of Listener
        manager=(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);//Getting the Telephony Service Object
        if(!isAlreadyListening)//Checking Listener is Not Registered with Telephony Services
        {
              manager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);//Registering the Listener with Telephony to listen the State Change
          isAlreadyListening=true;  //setting true to indicate that Listener is listening the Phone State
        }

    }

}
`
```

Android Manifest.xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pavan.phonecall"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /><!-- Permission for Reading Phone State -->
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <!--  If this app is not running then this will be automatically called when phone state change detected(Look at Intent Filter) -->
        <receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>`
```

When i install from eclipse , it says apk installed. When i call my phone, Toast message doesnt pop up. where am i going wrong? please help! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install the app, it stays in `stopped` state until you start the application with some UI control (i.e. `Activity`). It became compulsory from [Android 3.1 APIs (API 12)](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols).

So ultimately, you need at least one `Activity` in your application apart from just `BroadcastReceiver` to move your app out of that `stopped` state. Otherwise it will not receive any broadcasts.

**Reference:**

[Launch Controls](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols)

Comment: then how do i write a background service for the same? after i install, it should just monitor. a hidden activity or window may be?

Comment: you can use same code for that purpose but what you need is at least one `Activity` which can start your app.

Comment: So how do I hide my activity?

Comment: @PavanKumar: you can try to create `Widget` for your app and try to use it to move your app out of stopped state.